# How to combine columns with different rows with R

Tags: r

I have several excel files and need to combine the fourth column of each table. However, the rows of the table are different. Some of them have 7 rows but some of them have 5 or 6 rows. Here are my data descriptions.

[image]

As you can see, there are three excel files and I need to merge the fourth column. One of them has 7 rows while the other two has 5 and 6 rows. I try to use a loop reading all files inside a folder and then use "merge" to do this.

Here is my code.

```
rm(list=ls())
updir = "D:/STAR/MergeResults/Rtest"
library(readxl)

setwd(updir)    #set up the working dictionary

outfile <- ""   #first define an empty variable

file_list <- list.files(pattern = NULL) 

for (i in 1:length(file_list)) {
   file <- read_excel(file_list[i],col_names = TRUE) 
   variable <- file[,4]
   outfile <-merge(outfile,variable)
}
```

Can anyone help me merge these columns with different rows?

Comment: what do you mean by merge? Are you expecting a vector that is a combination of those columns? Or a dataframe with a single column that is all of those columns combined into a single column? Please post an example of your desired output.

Comment: @Wil, thanks for your help. I expect to have a vector that is a combination of those columns. Again, appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way `outfile` is initialized so that it is an empty vector. You can combine vectors using the `c()` function. The rest of your code can remain the same.

```r
cols <- apply(file_list,function(x) {
  read_excel(file_list[i],col_names = TRUE)[,4]
})

max_length <- max(sapply(cols,length))

outfile <- data.frame(x = 1:max_length)

for(v in cols) {
  vmod <- c(v,rep(NA,max_length - length(v)))
  outfile <- cbind(outfile,vmod)
}

outfile <- outfile[,-1]
```

write to excel:

```r
library(openxlsx)

write.xlsx(outfile, file = "NewFile.xlsx", colNames = TRUE,rowNames = FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks again for your replying. I could successfully run this code. Could you mind giving some suggestions about how to export the outfile result to excel? Really Appreciate! @Wil

Comment: thanks for helping. But i got some error when I export the outfile to excel. Here is my error information.  Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 5, 6

Comment: Can you update your post with the result of `dput(outfile)` after you have run your code?

Comment: Here is the result of "dput(output)   > dput(outfile)
list(n29186rate = c(0.0825524697361693, 0.377069429016746, 0.291790226423568, 
0.172935239234481, 0.0656152781639442, 0.00789028424747087, 0.00214707317773692
), n4279rate = c(0.0625460387937829, 0.0529293569833717, 0.236273183815874, 
0.260711631098072, 0.387539789309644), n897rate = c(0.0160392703269569, 
0.101338733302453, 0.369911087395438, 0.345991365347504, 0.12898237564171, 
0.0377371679867873))

Comment: I have updated my answer. Note the addition of `outfile <- unlist(outfile)` in the first section and the addition of `rowNames = FALSE` in the call to `write.xlsx()`

Comment: Thanks for helping. I could run this code. But the final result is an excel including just one column. Could you offer some suggestions about how to merge them into three columns in one excel file? I feel very embarrassed to ask you so many questions. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: I have made some changes that may or may not work, I can't test exactly without your excel files. This is a very unnatural data structure for R. By definition, all columns in a dataframe must have the same number of rows; see the *Details* section of  `?data.frame`. I would encourage you to read Hadley's paper on [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) and think about the most appropriate structure for your data.